# Unity change Super+D shortcut

Tags: 16.04, unity, shortcut-keys, compiz, shortcuts

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity.

Is possible to change Super+D shortcut?. I have changed in Configuration --> Keyboard --> Navigation --> Hide all normal windows, but this has not effect.

I want to put "Hide all windows" in Super+V and for this I have disabled lenses using next command:

```
$ dconf write /com/canonical/unity/dash/scopes "['home.scope']"
```

Note: I have installed Compiz Manager.

Comment: I'll have to look into it a bit more tomorrow, but it seems that the shortcut is hard coded in Unity. We can however add another shortcut (Super+V if you disabled it) to show (toggle) desktop. Would you consider that to be usefull? Super+D would also still work. I cannot find a dconf key in `dconf dump /` that would disable that one. Going to sleep now...

Comment: Yes, I think is hardcoded too, but with what action? I supposed that "hardcoded problem" would disappear with dconf command... At this moment, Super+V don't show videos... And yeah, Super+D still working, this is not a big problem for me because I can use Super+D... but I want to know if anyone have a solution for this, I'm curious about this "problem". Thanks for your interest !!!

Comment: Hi Dani, If it is coded into Unity, with no option to disable (that's how it looks), we cannot get rid of it, *but*, we can add a script to do the very same to the shortcut Super+V. I will post it if you think that's useful.

Comment: Hi, I edited my post. I do not know if there has been a confusion, but the thing I want is to put Super+D (hide all windows) in Super+V, not the opposite. Obviously this is not a very important issue because at the moment I can use Super+D, but i'm curious about this. And thank you again :D.

Comment: Haha, yes I got that. See my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to make Super + v switch/toggle to the desktop

I *was* busy writing a script for it, but then a simple, pragmatic solution popped into my mind:

1. Install [xdotool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/yakkety/man1/xdotool.1.html), to simulate key press:

   ```
   sudo apt install xdotool
   ```
2. Disable <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> by the command:

   ```
   gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Dash scopes ['']
   ```
3. Create a custom shortcut: choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "sleep 0.3 && xdotool key Super+d"
   ```

   to  <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>.

Now pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> will toggle the desktop.

#### Explanation

Since you don't mind leaving <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> exist, you can make <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> *virtually* press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, with the help of xdotool, running the command:

```
xdotool key Super+d
```

The `sleep 0.3` is to make sure the *real* key press does not interfere with the virtual one.

Comment: Yeah, this works. Thanks you very much for your effort, I didn't know anything about xdotool, this is a tool for simulate keypress?... so you can program in C, for example, and use it for simulate other things, no?. Other question, the reason why you use sleep is for avoid system detect Super+D and Super+V pressed at same time?

Comment: @Dani ah, great that you like it :) Indeed, one of the things you can do with xdotool is simulate key press. The break is to prevent the virtual keypress to be at the same time as the resl one, which would make an unwanted press altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to system `settings` -> `keyboard` -> `shortcuts`. From there you can select the navigation menu, search for the hide all windows entry, click on the present shortcut (e.g. `Super`+`d`), and enter enter your new shortcut (press `Super`+`v`)

[image]

Comment: Uhm, that's exactly what OP mentioned *not* to work, which I can confirm. Did you try?

Comment: Not working by this way...

Comment: Or I blatantly read over it, or OP edited the question. Anyways, if you click on the right-hand column with the shortcut, it will ask you to enter the shortcut. It works for me running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Not here, also 16.04. Please *try* the shortcut afterwards. *Seems* to be hard-coded.

Comment: hold on, let me take a picture of what I mean

Comment: @Peetah what you mean is clear, it just has no effect.

Comment: Added in the picture, not to question anyones intelligence, but just to be really clear.

Sorry for it being in Dutch

Comment: Yeah, I have changed this (like your screenshot) and I used Super + V, but this has no effect, sorry

Comment: @Peetah please again, it is the first thing I tried, it *seems* to work, but has no effect. Try it.

Comment: In that case I am afraid I can not help you. I hope you find the solution soon though.

Comment: Sorry to bring this up again, but isn't  Super + v already taken by the dash to search in videos? Have you tried Ctrl + Super + v?

Comment: Yeah, I have disabled Super + v for this reason with dconf command above. Ctrl + Super + v has not effect too.